# Error: property "count" not found on object of type "TableItem*"

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am converting Swift code to Objective-C as an exercise.

In ViewController.m

```
  - (NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return self.items[section].count;
    }
```

Error: property "count" not found on object of type "TableItem*"

Original Swift code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].count
}
```

Viewcontroller.swift

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let now = NSDate()
    var date = NSDate()

    var sections:[String] = []
    var items:[[TableItem]] = []
```

...

Comment: so are you writing this in swift or obj-c? and how is `items` defined?

Comment: Where is the declaration of `items`?

Comment: It should be self.items.count.

Comment: OOPS ! I forgot some code >__< brb !

Comment: display your declaration of items variable in objective-c.

Comment: Items is multidimention array?

Comment: Oops. Sorry  ! Note taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C header we can see that `items` is a `NSMutableArray` of `TableItem` objects, so by `self.items[section].count;` you get `TableItem` at index `section` and there is no `count` method or property – that's why you get the error.

The question remains if you wish for `TableItem` class to have `count` property/method, or you really meant to create array of arrays of `TableItem` objects to separate sections by putting items into different tables.

If you want to have just one section and items aren't supposed to be divided anyhow, then use

```
return self.items.count;
```

and you are good to go.

If I got your intentions wrong, please provide declaration code of `items` in Swift.

**Edit:**

So, instead of

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<TableItem *> *items;
```

you need

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<NSMutableArray<TableItem *> *> *items;
```

Comment: @CodeOxO you still haven't posted declaration code of `items` in Swift.

Comment: @CodeOxO That proves my point. You have array of arrays of TableItem in Swift (that's why it works) and array of TableItem in Objective-C. Change the declaration in Objective-C and it will be ok.

Comment: Could you please add the code to your answer so I can accept it :D ?

Comment: @CodeOxO Done. I hope I haven't made any typo because I can't get to anything with Xcode installed now. The idea is that you need to have NSArray of NSArrays of TableItems. The code looks a bit ugly, but at least now we can specify the types stored in collection, which wasn't possible in Objective-C before Swift.

Comment: Great ! You rock ! Also gave you + 1!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your "items" should be an array of arrays. Now you trying to get a property named "count" from an instance of TableItem class which haven't such property.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return ((TableItem *)self.items[section]).count;
}
```

You should only cast the item[section]

Comment: Are "items" is an array of TableItem that mean you should return directly self.items.count

Comment: items[section].count is meant that items is an array of array